# Delete part of string in line (but not whole line) in subset of rows?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited text file with 4 columns and a hundred million rows that looks like this:

```
chr1    10019   10020   rs775809821
chr2    10108   10109   rs376007522
chr3    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr4    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr5    10138   10139   rs368469931
chr6    10146   10147   rs779258992
chr7    10165   10165   rs796884232
chr8_KI270718v1_random  10149   10150   rs371194064
chr9_GL000221v1_random  10144   10145   rs144773400
chr10_KI270879v1_alt    10055   10055   rs768019142
chr11_KI270714v1_random 10107   10108   rs62651026
```

I want to delete the portion of the first column that starts with "_" from the lines that contain this. So I want the output to look like:

```
chr1    10019   10020   rs775809821
chr2    10108   10109   rs376007522
chr3    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr4    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr5    10138   10139   rs368469931
chr6    10146   10147   rs779258992
chr7    10165   10165   rs796884232
chr8    10149   10150   rs371194064
chr9    10144   10145   rs144773400
chr10   10055   10055   rs768019142
chr11   10107   10108   s62651026
```

I have tried doing this using sed (`sed 's/_\S*\s*/ /' infile > outfile`), but this only removed the "_" in lines that contain the string I wanted to remove. So it looked something like this:

```
chr1    10019   10020   rs775809821
chr2    10108   10109   rs376007522
chr3    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr4    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr5    10138   10139   rs368469931
chr6    10146   10147   rs779258992
chr7    10165   10165   rs796884232
chr8 KI270718v1_random  10149   10150   rs371194064
chr9 GL000221v1_random  10144   10145   rs144773400
chr10 KI270879v1_alt    10055   10055   rs768019142
chr11 KI270714v1_random 10107   10108   s62651026
```

How can I delete only the portion of the line from "_" onwards only in lines containing a string following "chr#" in column 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1 ~ /chr/{sub(/_.*$/, "", $1)} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
chr1   10019  10020  rs775809821
chr2   10108  10109  rs376007522
chr3   10128  10128  rs796688738
chr4   10128  10128  rs796688738
chr5   10138  10139  rs368469931
chr6   10146  10147  rs779258992
chr7   10165  10165  rs796884232
chr8   10149  10150  rs371194064
chr9   10144  10145  rs144773400
chr10  10055  10055  rs768019142
chr11  10107  10108  rs62651026
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sed -r 's/_\S+//' file
```

note that it's not limited to the first column though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^\t_]+)_[^\t]+/\1/' file
chr1    10019   10020   rs775809821
chr2    10108   10109   rs376007522
chr3    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr4    10128   10128   rs796688738
chr5    10138   10139   rs368469931
chr6    10146   10147   rs779258992
chr7    10165   10165   rs796884232
chr8    10149   10150   rs371194064
chr9    10144   10145   rs144773400
chr10   10055   10055   rs768019142
chr11   10107   10108   rs62651026
```